# how to use confirm function with sweetalert in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

I got a tag that calls function called `cancel()` in HTML.

```
<a onclick="return cancel();" href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/views/pay/user/plan.jsp"></a>
```

This is how function `cancel()` looks like in JavaScript.

```
function cancel() { 
    return confirm("My Message");
};
```

If I hit ok button, the page should go back to the designated page.
Or If I hit cancel button, the page should be stay at the same page.

The codes above works fine as I expected except the design.

I want to apply Sweetalert (whatever its version is one or two) to my confirm window.
However, as I far as I searched, I could only find things that confirm 'yes' button never makes the page moves to the designated one.

I wonder Sweetalert is literally for plain alert?

Comment: Your code only "works" because it relies on the fact that `confirm()` blocks the execution of the script until the user responds. Sweetalert cannot do that, it is async. Therefore you need to do more work like `preventDefault` on the event, then navigate the user if they confirm the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Niet mentioned, only `confirm()` has the privilege to stop the execution.
In order to use SweetAlert, you should stop the redirection by calling `preventDefault()`, show the alert, wait for the user interaction and if they want to proceed, do the redirection by yourself (`location.href = ...` ).

```js
function confirm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      buttons: true,
      dangerMode: true,
    })
    .then((toContinue) => {
      if (toContinue) {
        location.href = e.target.href;
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="return confirm(event)" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Navigate</a>
```

https://jsbin.com/sugavat/edit?html,js,output